# adding a div within a div tag to display on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a div in my tag and when i hover over the  tag i would like to display the div. How can i do with what i currently have?

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
  <a class="ui_title accordion-toggle text_x-large unit_accordion_toggle" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  <i class="icon icon_grey icon_user float_right" style="margin-top:-30px; margin-right:16px"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add a div tag (manually) which is then shown/hidden by hovering (jquery), or are you asking how to add a div tag and showing/hiding it by hovering all in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/UE55v/)?

HTML

```
<a href='#'>
    Show Content
    <div>Content</div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
a div{
    display:none;
}
a:hover div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can add the `<div>` inside:

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="ui_title accordion-toggle text_x-large unit_accordion_toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
    </a>
    <i class="icon icon_grey icon_user float_right" style="margin-top:-30px; margin-right:16px"> </i>
    <div class="hidden">This is the div to show</div>
</div>
```

Second hide the div:

```
.hidden {
   display:none;
}
```

Finally set the CSS selector `:hover` to show the inside div:

```
.accordion-heading:hover .hidden{
  display:block;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/gEWve/3/

Comment: Using css over javascript is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#accordion-heading").hover(function(){
    $(this).append("<div id='some_div'>Text goes here</div>")
},function(){
    $("#some_div").remove();
});
```

If you already have a hidden div in your original div, it would be easier to just show and hide it.

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="ui_title accordion-toggle text_x-large unit_accordion_toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
    </a>
    <i class="icon icon_grey icon_user float_right" style="margin-top:-30px; margin-right:16px"> </i>
    <div id="childdiv" style="display:none">This is the div to show</div>
</div>

 $("#accordion-heading").hover(function(){
        $("#childdiv").show();
 },function(){
        $("#childdiv").hide();
 });
```

Comment: OK. Answer using javascript is acceptable and a good reference

Comment: He did tag it Javascript and jQuery, and we all know that [you can never have enough jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that you could use a fade transition on the element with css by setting the opacity to 0 and then to 100 while using -webkit-transition.

Note: only supported in modern browsers that use webkit

```
a div{
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
a:hover div{
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xV62K/